# NSDate timeIntervalSinceNow and local timezone?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nstimeinterval, nstimezone

I'm doing a calculation to find the `NSTimeInterval` between a known `futureDate` (which is in GMT/UTC) and the current time (and timezone) where the device currently resides.

```
NSTimeInterval approachInterval = [futureDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
```

I know that `NSDate` does not store any timeZone specific data, this rather being something that is calculated when the date needs displaying on the device.

My question is that from my initial tests (I'm currently in GMT+0001) it seems that the `NSTimeInterval` returned does not account for my local timezone. Do I have to manually calculate the timezone offset and remove that from my interval, and what would be the best way of doing that given that I can't supply an `NSDate` with a correct timezone (using `timeIntervalSinceDate:` for example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSDate` represents a single point in time. It does not have (and does not need!!) a time zone. So *"a known futureDate (which is in GMT/UTC)"* or *"I can't supply an NSDate with a correct timezone"* does not make sense.

`[futureDate timeIntervalSinceNow]` returns the time interval between `futureDate` and the
current date and time and is completely independent of any time zones.

If you do not get the expected result, then perhaps your calculation of `futureDate` was wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I understand that, I said known futureDate because that date is actually in UTC +0000 so should be right relative to what you would get back from doing [NSDate date]; I see your point, by forgetting the timeZone both NSTimeInterval and my futureDate are both at +0000 so the relative span between them should be correct. I will check the rounding and make sure I am not dropping a few intervals somewhere in my calculations. Much appreciated.